# как из блока if передать значение переменной в блок else в С/С++

Tags: c++, c

Мне нужно из блока if передать правильное значение переменной backup_dir в блок else. Если просто написать эту переменную в блоке else то она будет пуста, я думаю всем понятно почему. Так вот как это сделать? Наверняка необходимо использовать указатели или же ссылки, я пробовал, но у меня не получилось.

```
 if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    do
    {
        if (strcmp(".", fd.cFileName) != 0 && strcmp("..", fd.cFileName) != 0)
        {
            if (fd.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                char res[MAX_PATH] = { '\0' };
                sprintf(backup_dir, "%s\\%s", "bin\\backup", fd.cFileName);
                CreateDirectory(backup_dir, NULL);
                fast_move_files(res, path_for_dir);
            }
            else
            {
                sprintf(backup, "%s\\%s", "bin\\backup", fd.cFileName);
                printf("back-up path %s\n", backup);
                std::ofstream f(backup, std::ios::app);
            }
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(handle, &fd));
```

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что если условие истинно, то в ветвь else вы не попадёте?

Comment: Я не настолько глуп, чтобы этого не понимать. Код устроен так что 2 ветви рано или поздно выполнятся

Comment: @S1NGer-iwni- Если Вы знаете что такое область видимости переменой, значит знаете что переменная `backup_dir`должна быть инициализирована корректно до ее использования. Значит Вам нужно переделать алгоритм или в начале формировать дерево каталогов и файлов или гарантировано вначале возвращать каталог а потом файлы в нем. Что возвращает  `FindNextFile` ?

Comment: В с++17 можно также `if(int myvar = 42 ; i > 100) {} else { cout << myvar; }`

Comment: спасибо попробую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

во-первых у каждой переменной есть область видимости, т.е. откуда к ней можно обратиться

к переменной, определённой внутри скобок `{...}` можно обратиться только внутри этих же скобок (всякую экзотику не рассматриваем),

поэтому когда вы переменную определили в блоке `else` - то это именно переменная в блоке `else` и к другим переменным выше отношения не имеет

поэтому чтобы иметь доступ к переменной и из `if` блока и из `else` ее надо определить выше

```
        char backup_dir[MAX_PATH];
        if (fd.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            // backup_dir видна и тут
        }
        else
        {
            // backup_dir видна и тут
        }
```

А во вторых и это более важно - если ваше условие истинно, то вы входите только в `if {...}` и не входите (не будет выполняться) в `else {...}`

так что если вы что-то записали в одном блоке, во втором вы этим не сможете воспользоваться потому что просто сам блок не будет выполняться - только один или другой блог (дудочка и кувшинчик :))

Возможно вы хотите как-то использовать переменную `backup_dir` внутри цикла `while`, тогда ее надо поднять еще выше:

```
char backup_dir[MAX_PATH];
do
{
    if (strcmp(".", fd.cFileName) != 0 && strcmp("..", fd.cFileName) != 0)
    {
        if (fd.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            // если backup_dir была изменена тут
        }
        else
        {
            // но в одном из этапов цикла `while` backup_dir можно использовать и тут
            // только надо проверить, что переменная содержит значение, ведь это условие может сработать раньше, чем условие выше, где переменной присваивается значение и создаётся папка
        }
    }
} while (FindNextFile(handle, &fd));
```

Comment: Во-первых, я прекрасно знаю что такое область видимости переменных и в этих словах я это подчеркнул: `Если просто написать эту переменную в блоке else то она будет пуста, я думаю всем понятно почему`. Во-вторых, этот код устроен так что рано или поздно выполнятся блок и if и else. И в-третьих, переменная backup_dir может быть иницилизирована только в блоке if , и мне очень важно передать ее значение в блок else, так как в блоке if backup_dir получает path до папки необходимой для бэкапа, а в else я получаю path до файлов и надо передать переменную в другой блок, чтобы сделать хороший бэкап

Comment: также я пробовал это раньше `только надо проверить, что переменная содержит значение, ведь это условие может сработать раньше, чем условие выше, где переменной присваивается значение и создаётся папка`. Не помогло

Comment: `Во-вторых, этот код устроен так что рано или поздно выполнятся блок и if и else.` - вообще-то если это происходит в разных этапах цикла, то это совершенно разные блоки и не совсем корректно говорить про то, что 'и в блоке if и в блоке else' и приведите тогда пожалуйста весь код, в котором `Не помогло` - чтобы более точно понять, что происходит, например что такое `fast_move_files` - это вызов самой себя или это иная функция?

Comment: Если вы знаете, что такое область видимости, то ваш вопрос как минимум странен. "Странен, если не сказать большего" (с) :)